# Having Problems w/ Java Runtime

Tags: java

Help me I am new to Java and am currently doing a school project which needs me to use runtime to use netsh to find WLAN ssid and mac addresses. However the console keep giving me this (Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.165] (c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.) How do i make it display the netsh command output instead

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

}

public void getWLANbssidInfo() {
    String netsh = "netsh wlan show networks mode = bssid";

    try {
        Process p1;
        p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c " + netsh);
        p1.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p1.getInputStream()));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while(line!=null){
            System.out.println(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("There was an IO exception.");
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println("The command was interrupted.");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your code would be easier to read if it was consistently indented.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `exec()` overload that accepts a `String[]` to specify command and arguments of the command such as :

```
p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd", "/c", "netsh"});
```

Note that you may also run the `netsh` command without the cmd command if the executable is included the environment path or the working directory (that you can set) where you run the command:

```
p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netsh");
```

Answer (score 1):

You must pass the parameters to `exec()` as separate words.

Here’s one way:

```
p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(("cmd /c " + netsh).split("\\s+"));
```

Comment: for some reason when running it, the console will terminate it do you have any idea why?